# How I fetch cummulative course credits with differenct conditions.

Tags: sql

Requirement:

1. If student passed 12 credit out of 15 in 1st semester then it sum
   only passed credit.
2. If this student passed this credit in 2nd semester then in sum only
   passed credit of certain course is count but if this student don't  opt this course in
   2nd semester then failed credits count in sum.
3. 2nd time repeat course again fail then if passed in 3rd semester it
   should count in sum other wise fail then it count in 2nd semester
   fail credit of certain course.

Query is which not working properly is :

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN (A1.repeat_candidate='N' AND GRADE_POINTS!=0 ) 
                   THEN a1.unt_TAKEN 
                 WHEN (REPEAT_CANDIDATE='N'AND GRADE_POINTS=0) 
                   THEN a1.unt_TAKEN 
                 WHEN (a1.REPEAT_CANDIDATE='Y'AND a1.GRADE_POINTS!=0)  
                  THEN a1.unt_TAKEN 
            END)
FROM PS_CLASS_TBL_SE_VW a1 
WHERE a1.STDNT_ENRL_STATUS='E'
GROUP BY a1.emplid
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Always construct a SQL Fiddle for your questions, so one can better understand the problem.